# Coordinates adapted to transverse intersections of two submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $N_1,N_2\subseteq M$ two submanifolds intersecting transversely, i.e.
$$T_pN_1+T_pN_2=T_pM$$
for all $p\in N_1\cap N_2$. It is a standard result that $N_1\cap N_2$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$.

> Let $p\in N_1\cap N_2$. Can we find a local chart $\varphi:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$ for $M$ around $p$ such that
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> \varphi(N_1\cap U) &= \mathbb{R}^{n_1}\times\{0\} \\
> \varphi(N_2\cap U) &= \{0\}\times\mathbb{R}^{n_2}
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   and hence $\varphi(N_1\cap N_2\cap U)=\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}^{m-n_1-n_2}\times\{0\}$?